# How to execute command by python?

Tags: python, command, cd

I want to give a directory from `raw_input` of user and have `cd` to that directory by python

I used that code but it doesn't work for me:

```
a=raw_input("Enter The Dir :")
import os
os.system("cd "+a)
```

but it doesn't change the current directory of the python program!

Comment: @Bakuriu - you should create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the current directory of a python program you should call [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()   # show current working directory (cwd)
'/home/username'
>>> os.chdir('Downloads')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/username/Downloads'
```

Running the `cd` command via [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) doesn't work because `os.system` executes the command-line passed as argument in a new shell. From the documentation:

> **Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.** This is implemented by
>   calling the Standard C function `system()`, and has the same
>   limitations.

The `cd` command actually *does* work, the problem is that it changes the current directory *of the newly created shell*, not of the current running python process.  Using `os.system('cd ' + x)` is the same as doing:

```
$$(cd Downloads)    #execute in a subshell
$pwd
/home/username
```

While calling `os.chdir` is equivalent to:

```
$cd Downloads
$pwd
/home/username/Downloads
```

i.e. it actually changes the current working directory as you want.

---

Note that `os.system` should be *avoided*. Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead. This is even mentioned in the documentation for `os.system`:

> The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; **using that module is
>   preferable to using this function.** See the [Replacing Older Functions
>   with the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section in the `subprocess` documentation for
>   some helpful recipes.

The `subprocess` module gives you much more control over the execution of the commands.
In fact your current code has a *huge* security flaw. For example what if the user entered a directory called (**WARNING**: do not provide this path to the abovementioned program. It will wipe your home directory!):

```
~;rm -fr .
```

While using `subprocess` you can avoid to get it interpreted as a shell command. For example:

```
import subprocess

dir_name = raw_input('Insert directory: ')
subprocess.call(['ls', dirname])
```

when provided with the above path will simply try to list the contents of a directory called `~;rm -fr .` (a valid UNIX path), which probably doesn't exist.
While:

```
import os
dir_name = raw_input('Insert directory: ')
os.system('ls ' + dir_name=)
```

Will first list the contents of `~` (aka, your home directory), and then it will wipe the home.

Comment: Thank you my friend :)

OK

We Changed the Directory.....

but now:

For example i wanna make a backdoor by weevely

How do i get password from my user????

the normal command for make weevely.php is this:

    ./weevely.py generate example
in this command "example" is password of that file


but i wanna get the password from my user by raw_input and make a backdoor for him with the password that he entered !

How do it?

Comment: @user3741774 If you want to request a password from the user you should use the [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) module. I don't understand your reference to a backdoor, which would be an illegal practice that cannot be discussed on SO. If you have other doubts you may open a new question.

Comment: my problem Fixed ! But how do i can copy file from a directory on the directory that my python script is here ????????